# dynamic drop down menu disappearing

Tags: html, css, dynamic, menu

i know this has been asked a few times here already and i have read through all of the question and answers, and tried all of the suggestions in an attempt to fix this. I have been trying now for three weeks and i am going to have to admit defeat and ask for help.
I think that the other solutions haven't worked because my site is built using an adobe Business Catalyst template.
http://lahcen.businesscatalyst.com the hover is on About Us and Experience, the sub menu just disappears really quickly.

any help would be hugely appreciated

Comment: thanks Portland Runner that is perfect, and i will make sure i provide more info in future, sorry x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really should provide some more code, including your css for the menu's and hover actions.  I did a quick play with styles and found that if you increase your line-height greater than 1.5 you'll get a smooth transition (Only tried Chrome).  It looks like there is a gap between your drop down and the main menu bar.  When the cursor is between the two it's no longer on the hover.

```
#navigation ul {
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
```

It's not a perfect fix but should lead you in the right direction.